# jquery mobile cancel pagebeforeshow event

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile, is there a way to cancel page showing at the pagebeforeshow event? I have some permission check code at pagebeforeshow and I want to direct user to sign in page if permission is not met.

```
$("secretpage").live("pagebeforeshow", function () {
  if (permissionNotMet()) {
    stopShowingPage()         //    <---- how?
    $.mobile.changePage("#signin")
  }
})
```

Comment: Good question, I gave it a few minutes of messing around and I couldn't get the initial page transition to cancel before transitioning to the redirect-page.

Comment: I agree that I should put code at the log in step. I just think it would be wise to have permission check on the actual page as well..

Comment: `pagebeforeload` can be canceled, so if you check if the user has the correct permissions on `pagebeforeload` you can cancel the page-load and redirect the user to the login page. I'm pretty sure this event only fires when navigating to external pages, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you were asking for, but you can re-work the flow of your code to make this easier on yourself.

Handle the submission of your login form by yourself, then direct the user to the correct page based on the server response:

```
$(document).delegate('#login', 'pageinit', function () {
    function loginSuccess (serverResponse) {

        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

        //here you check the `serverResponse` and direct the user where they need to go
    }
    function loginError (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
    $(this).find('form').bind('submit', function () {

        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

        $.ajax({ url : '<url>', data : $(this).serialize(), success : loginSuccess, error : loginError });
        return false;
    });
});
```

You will also need to add `data-ajax="false"` as an attribute to the `<form>` tag so that jQuery Mobile doesn't handle the submission for you.